# Clipping raster by specific polygon in layer using PyQGIS in Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I have one raster and one vector layer and I need to clip raster by each specific feature (polygon) from vector layer.
So basically I need array of vector layers.

Only answers I found is to mask by whole vector layer.

Is there a way to do that in python console?

I tried with

```
    
    alg_name = 'gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer'
    params = {'INPUT': rl[0],
          'MASK': boulder.geometry().boundingBox(),
          'NODATA': 255.0,
          'ALPHA_BAND': False,
          'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
          'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
          'OPTIONS': '-of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW',
          'DATA_TYPE': 0,  # Byte
          'OUTPUT': 'test',
          }
    result = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the features in your mask layer and use the [materialize](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ab95bcca99b1d5c082ca409da04e280b9) method to create an in-memory vector layer containing each feature in turn, and use that as the `'MASK'` parameter for the clip algorithm.

```py
import os

output_folder = r'Path/To/Destination/Folder'

raster_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Name_of_raster_layer')[0]
mask_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Name_of_vector_layer')[0]

for ft in mask_layer.getFeatures():
    temp_lyr = mask_layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest([ft.id()]))
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f'Clipped_raster_{ft.id()}.tif')
    params = {'INPUT':raster_layer,
                'MASK':temp_lyr,
                'SOURCE_CRS':None,
                'TARGET_CRS':None,
                'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
                'NODATA':None,
                'ALPHA_BAND':False,
                'CROP_TO_CUTLINE':True,
                'KEEP_RESOLUTION':False,
                'SET_RESOLUTION':False,
                'X_RESOLUTION':None,
                'Y_RESOLUTION':None,
                'MULTITHREADING':False,
                'OPTIONS':'',
                'DATA_TYPE':0,
                'EXTRA':'-co COMPRESS=LZW',
                'OUTPUT':output_path}
                
    processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", params)
    
print('Done')
```

Comment: Which DATA_TYPE should I use for double type of pixels.

Comment: @Tomislav Muic, if you need to explicitly specify the data type, then I guess Float32 (6) is probably what you want. But I suggest to put `0` for the `'DATA_TYPE'` parameter- that will tell the algorithm to use the input raster data type.